# A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'. error on val

Tags: flutter, dart

I meet an error on `val`. It says

```
A value of type 'String?' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'String'.
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropDown extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropDown({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropDown> createState() => _DropDownState();
}

class _DropDownState extends State<DropDown> {
  String dropdownValue = "Choose Currency";
  List<String> currnecy = ["SUTRAQ", "USD", "NGN"];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
        child: Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: DropdownButton<String>(
            value: dropdownValue,
            items: currnecy.map((String currencyName) {
              return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
                child: Text(currencyName),
                value: currencyName,
              );
            }).toList(),
            onChanged: (val) {
              setState(() {
                dropdownValue = val;
              });
            }),
      ),
    ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The parameter of the `onChanged` of the `DropdownButton` is nullable `String?`, so it means `val` can be `null`. You defined your variable `dropdownValue` as non-nullable (`String` and not `String?`) so it doesn't accept the `null` value.

I guess the value of the `onChanged` can be `null` if the user dismisses the dropdown without choosing any option.

You have several options:

### Option 1: Make your variable nullable:

```dart
  String? dropdownValue = "Choose Currency";
```

### Option 2: Ignore `val` when it is `null`:

```dart
onChanged: (val) {
  if (val == null) return;
  setState(() {
    dropdownValue = val;
  });
}),
```

### Option 3: Replace `val` with a non-nullable string:

```dart
onChanged: (val) {
  setState(() {
    dropdownValue = val ?? '';
  });
}),
```

Answer (score 1):

the method onChanged takes String? as a parameter:

```
onChanged: (String? value) {
    setState(() {
      dropdownValue = value;
    });
```

change: `String dropdownValue = "Choose Currency";`

to: `String? dropdownValue = "Choose Currency";`

OR change `val` in `onChanged` to nullable, like this:

```
onChanged: (val) {
          setState(() {
            dropdownValue = val!;
          });
```